# How to design a common static method in all classes implementing an interface

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, static, abstract

I have an interface called `Relation`, implemented by a class `BasicRelation`, and extended by subclasses (e.g. `ParentChild`, `Sibling`, `Spouse`). While developing my code, I realized that I often need a method which takes a `String` representation of a relation to create it. For example:

```
public class ParentChild implements Relation extends BasicRelation {

  // e.g. "Jack is Emily's father. Jill is her mother." will return the list
  // <ParentChild(Jack, Emily), ParentChild(Jill, Emily)>
  static List<ParentChild> fromSentence(String s) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now, since I find myself needing this method (`fromSentence(String)`) in every class, except perhaps in `BasicRelation`, I would like to move it *up* the hierarchy. The problem is that the internal details of the method is subclass-dependent, so I can't have it as a `static` method in the interface `Relation` or the superclass `BasicRelation`.

Unfortunately, in Java, it is also not possible to have a `static abstract` method.

Is there any way to ensure that every subclass of `BasicRelation` (or every class implementing `Relation`) implements `fromSentence(String)`? If no, should I be designing this in a completely different way? I guess this last question is more of a request for design-advice than a question.

Comment: No, there is no way to force the implementation of a `static` method.

Comment: Why does it need to be static?

Comment: Some kind of factory would better apply here.

Comment: or you could just use some other class with a static method such as fromSentence(String,Relation)?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: The factory approach does seem to be the most viable option. Is it possible (and *good design*) to create just one `Factory`, and make it return `List<? extends BasicRelation>`? Then perhaps use `instanceOf` on the list elements to do subclass-specific things?

Comment: Those _subclass-specific things_ should be done by the subclass through polymorphism. Or check out the Visitor pattern.

Comment: I think java 8 allows static methods in interface. please check http://www.journaldev.com/2752/java-8-interface-changes-static-methods-default-methods-functional-interfaces

Comment: Yes, it does. But the issue I wanted to discuss is about *enforcing* every subclass to implement a static method (which can't be done directly, as pointed out by @SotiriosDelimanolis).

Answer (score 1):

Why does the static method need to be in the interface? What's stopping you from having a 'Utility' class and having the method in there?

```
public class RelationUtility {
    public static BasicRelation relationFactory(String asString) {
        ....
    }
}
```

As a static method, there is no reason other than access to private members, which can also be accomplished by by 'default' permissions on those members....

Answer (score 0):

You can try making the BasicRelation class an abstract class and use an abstract fromSentence(..) method. This would require the ParentChild class to override and implement the fromSentence method because you can't create an object for ParentChild without implementing fromSentence()

```
public abstract class BasicRelation extends Relation(){

   public abstract List<..> fromSentence(String s);
}

public class ParentChild implements Relation extends BasicRelation {

 fromSentence(){
 //parentChild class's implementation
}
```

}

Comment: But static methods can't be abstract. That is essentially how my entire dilemma began. I would like to keep my method static becuase it's independent of a class instance; in fact, it is used to generate a list of instances.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right... you can try an approach like this

```
public class BasicRelation {

    public abstract List<ParentChild> fromSentenceInSubclass(s);

    public List<ParentChild> fromSentence(String s){
        fromSentenceInSubclass(s);
    }
}
```

And then you could have:

```
public class SubclassRelation extends BasicRelation {

    public List<ParentChild> fromSentenceInSubclass(s){
        // do subclass relation stuff
    }

}
```

You will probably need to change the code a bit and add some Generics around to make it happen the way you want.
Sotirios Delimanolis Factory suggestion might also be an option.

Comment: Both approaches suggested by you are fine for non-static methods. But I would like to keep the method static because it's being called to generate a list of subclass instances, and the method itself is independent of an instance.

Comment: Well, in this case, again, a Factory is indeed what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the abstract class BasicRelation include the static method which throws an Exception. That way you will be forced to override (shadow) the static method in the subclasses when you use it.

Something like:

```
public abstract class BasicRelation {
    public static List<..> fromSentence(String s) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm ... not sure if it's a good idea "design-wise", but definitely an interesting approach!